# GWT How to conditionally change text color

Tags: html, gwt

I have a text in my page. It's content changed based on what function called in service class.Like: Wait, Done, Please enter correct data, etc. What I want is to set the text color as black when it's content is "Wait" or "Done", else red.

My code in GWT layout page for it is :

```
if ((iscsiInfo.message == "Wait") || (iscsiInfo.message == "Done")) {

            messageHTML.getElement().getStyle().setColor("#000000");
        } else {
            messageHTML.getElement().getStyle().setColor("FF0000");

        }
```

It sets the text as black constantly using above code. Any idea how to figure it out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have missed the '#' in front of the color.

> messageHTML.getElement().getStyle().setColor("FF0000");

it should be

> messageHTML.getElement().getStyle().setColor("#FF0000");